# How to take Master/Detail Template and convert it into Navigation Drawer-type layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, master-detail, android-navigation

Over the past few days I've started to work with the Master/Detail template in Eclipse and I've been trying to figure out a way to take the generated Master/Detail template and convert it to have a navigation drawer-type UI. I imagine that it's possible to do, but how can I go about doing? What do I need to add/remove/modify in order to get similar/identical functionality to a navigation drawer using Master/Detail? I'm asking for assistance creating it using Master/Detail because I have tried other methods with no luck whatsoever. Also, how can I customize the look of it (background color, text color, etc.)?

Thank you in advance for any help in solving this! I have searched relentlessly for a solution with no results unfortunately so I hope that someone in the SO community can assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the Navigation Drawer is not appropriate for displaying Master/Detail data (i.e., it is only for navigation, not showing content), then you use the same steps as converting any `Activity` to using a Navigation Drawer. The Android training [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) goes into extensive detail with all the code you'd need to add a Navigation Drawer to an `Activity` and properly implement the [Navigation Drawer design pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

It may make sense to start with a simple `Activity`, then use what you learn there to apply it to the Master/Detail template.

Comment: I had forgotten to close out this question. I appreciate your assistance as it was what I needed. Thank you again!

Comment: Not a problem - happy to help!

Comment: Master detail works when we are using fragment in xml with API 11 with Layout Aliases, I'm looking for how to implement the same in navigation drawer where we are loading the fragment programmatically!

Comment: @LOG_TAG - layout aliases have been in Android since the beginning and support fragments can also be added via XML (although you'll note that the example does load the detail fragments programmatically already) - ask a separate question if you'd like assistance